# Removing space between Histograms in QGIS

Tags: qgis, histogram, diagram

I would like to remove the space between the bars in the histograms but I cannot find a way to do so.

See the image below for reference.

[image]

Comment: Hi @VV_61. I think I can answer your other question. I've been working with diagrams recently and I know I've done extensive formatting like what you ask. Only thing is, you need to post another question. Forum rules, as I explained in the answer.

Comment: 1) Hey, @VV_61. If you're still around and the answer was useful for you, you're supposed to mark the "accept" tick mark left of the answer text (should be greyed out and turn green upon clicking it). This lets the SEO know the question has been solved. 2) ALSO, I edited out the 2nd question you asked ("Also, is there an option to place the label right below the diagram?" since admins closed the question because of that. You should just ask it in a separate post and I'll answer it. It's an interesting aspect of QIGS's diagrams, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to adjust the 'Bar Spacing' variable in the 'Rendering' section of the 'Histogram' options to zero.

About your other question, site rules require that you ask one specific question per post. That way the search engine will be able to direct people looking for answers more efficiently. Consequently, it should asked in a separate question.

[image: 'Rendering' section of the 'Histogram' options]